# Define value in if statement not working

Tags: php

I'm working on an easy way to do edit the status of an Paypal payment system so i can switch it over in test mode when needed without going into the code. "MODULE_PAYMENT_PAYPAL_STANDARD_GATEWAY_SERVER" is defined to "Live", but for some reason it keep throwing the sandbox url.

```
echo MODULE_PAYMENT_PAYPAL_STANDARD_GATEWAY_SERVER ;

if (MODULE_PAYMENT_PAYPAL_STANDARD_GATEWAY_SERVER == "Live") {
    $form_action_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
  } else {
    $form_action_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
  }
echo ' '.$form_action_url;
die();
```

The above outputs:

> Live https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'

If I replace MODULE_PAYMENT_PAYPAL_STANDARD_GATEWAY_SERVER with 'live' it returns the value correctly, I also tried to move the DEFINE to a Variable before it goes to the IF statement, but it still doesn't work.

I'm using OsCommerce to define this via the admin system.

var_dump also shows:

> string(20) "Live"

instead of what it should:

> string(4) "Live"

Options for MODULE_PAYMENT_PAYPAL_STANDARD_GATEWAY_SERVER
is "Live" and "Sandbox".

Comment: Whats the other condition or is thre only one? i mean are thre other options the live? If not you can forget the live.

Comment: Show us your define statement.

Comment: added more information to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing and adding MODULE_PAYMENT_PAYPAL_STANDARD_GATEWAY_SERVER a few times without any changes I completely removed the paypal script from the site and installet it again. now it works!

Comment: I found the bug. An other person have tried to "improve" the speed, resulting in the last value from the config.xml fails for some reason. The way it reads it is not the best way so im going to fix it later. Simply just anoying that something that seems to be "right" is not right for some reasons...

Comment: If you accept this answer, it will mark the problem as resolved. Just editing "Solved" into the question still leaves it in the unanswered question pool.

Comment: Hmm did I accually forget this? well it is done now :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code works as expected:

```
<?php
    define("MODULE_PAYMENT_PAYPAL_STANDARD_GATEWAY_SERVER", "LIVE");
    echo MODULE_PAYMENT_PAYPAL_STANDARD_GATEWAY_SERVER ;

    if (MODULE_PAYMENT_PAYPAL_STANDARD_GATEWAY_SERVER == "Live") 
    {
        $form_action_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    } 
    else 
    {
        $form_action_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    }
    echo ' '.$form_action_url;
    die();
?>

// Outpu: Live https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
```

How exactly are you definine your constant?

When the following is changed:

```
define("MODULE_PAYMENT_PAYPAL_STANDARD_GATEWAY_SERVER", "LIVE");
```

the output is

```
LIVE https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
```

Edit: Based on your comment, the code is working exactly as it should then. You are defining your constant as `LIVE` but then checking it in your if statement against `Live`. When you compare them, they are *not* equal, therefore the `if` statement evaluates to false and your second condition is executed.

Comment: define("MODULE_PAYMENT_PAYPAL_STANDARD_GATEWAY_SERVER", "LIVE"); is located in a config.php that is loaded by require just above this if else statement

Comment: Im sorry, just copy/pasted your define.. Mine looks:  
define("MODULE_PAYMENT_PAYPAL_STANDARD_GATEWAY_SERVER", "Live") and output live which should make the if statement true.. right ?

Comment: @CasperO Yes, it should - and it does here on my system?

Comment: added more information to question - it also works fine in a "blank" php file.. so something is going wrong with my define.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(!defined('MODULE_PAYMENT_PAYPAL_STANDARD_GATEWAY_SERVER')) {
  define('MODULE_PAYMENT_PAYPAL_STANDARD_GATEWAY_SERVER', 'Live');
}

if(MODULE_PAYMENT_PAYPAL_STANDARD_GATEWAY_SERVER == 'Live') {
 echo('live');
} else {
 echo('sandboxing');
}
?>
```

Shows **live** ;-))

Works as expected - can NOT reproduce your described result.

Comment: Didn't work for me, for some reason its just not my lucky day with if else statements.

Comment: My provided example definitely works :-p... Check it in a blank php file.

Comment: Execute a ``var_dump(MODULE_PAYMENT_PAYPAL_STANDARD_GATEWAY_SERVER);`` and print the output here. I guess you are having a whitespace somewhere ;-))...

Comment: Added as exstra info in my question.